# Is hamburger menu aka navigation drawer deprecated

Tags: navigation, android, hamburger

We are in design phase of our new android app and for navigation we are considering navigation drawer but after some research I found that some apps are switching from navigation menu to tab based ui e.g. Facebook is now not using hamburger menu even it has lots of options to show. recently g+ app also replaced hamburger menu with drop down.

So should we go for hamburger menu or consider it bad design for user engagement and replace it with tab based ui?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all depends on the app itself and users' expectations.

For instance, users expect Facebook's desktop website to always show:

- Friend requests
- Their messages
- New notifications

The other options are hidden in menus and sub-menus. So, it's a logical step for Facebook to match the desktop version with the app.

If you have the screen space to place the prominent parts of your app in a tabbed-based layout, by all means, go for it.

On the issue of the navigation drawer being deprecated, I believe it's exactly the opposite. Most users recognize this behaviour pretty well.

Google just streamlined all of their apps/websites to use the navigation drawer:

[image]